# Connection object scope

Tags: scope, connection

I have a public static Connection `getConnection()` to get the DB connection and I have declared the connection object as static.
public static Connection con;
My doubt is as there could be multiple connections by concurrent users should I have the con as a local variable with in `getConnection()` or static would be fine?

Please point out what issues I would run into for concurrent users if the con object is static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're declaring a Connection **as static**, only one user at a time is able to connect to a database. This way you are creating an unnecessary bottleneck. Another question is: how do you maintain opening and closing a connection?

Your second proposition, creating **a local variable**, seems to eliminate the bottlenecking. But opening a connection each time you need to access a database is quite expensive.

So actually the answer is you should use a [**Connection Pool**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool). An established connection may be leased from a pool and used without an additional overhead.

Comment: Thank you Kuba. So, my next question is (1) if I am using JBoss or Tomcat server then should I be using servers's connection pooling (2) I have to write my own code, get 10/20 connections and maintain in a array list and close them after used/ (3) is there any utility or library available that can be used.

Comment: 1. Yes, the configuration is described in respective documentations  2. Under no circumstances should you implement it yourself unless you want to take it as a didactive challenge.                               3. There are DBCP and c3po libraries. The former has a record of discontinuous developement and honestly I don't know its current state. The latter has been successfully utilized in heavy load projects. There's also the BoneCP library but I know nothing about it.

Comment: Thank you again. Appreciate it.